# Another tag merge request: system-numbers and dialer-codes

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

[system-numbers](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/system-numbers) should be a synonym for [dialer-codes](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dialer-codes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tags where merged by Al Everett. :-)